# How to continue a class with another class and at the same time with same variable from first class

Tags: python, function, class, selenium, oop

I want to create a selenium test using functions and classes. The first file and first class is:

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class DriverAndLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
       self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_login(self):
       driver = self.driver
       driver.get('https://qa.knolyx.com/')
       self.assertIn("Login to your account | Knolyx", driver.title)
       time.sleep(1)
       search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
       search_box.send_keys('username@test.com')
       password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
       password.send_keys("98765")
       button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div > div > form > div.Login_Actions > button')
       button_login.click()
       time.sleep(1)
       self.assertIn("Dashboard | Knolyx", driver.title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
```

I want to create another file and class to continue first file and class. So, the code above acces the Knolyx site and login, and my second file I want to continue from login forwards.
I tried with:

```
  from SeleniumOOP import DriverAndLogin
  import unittest
  import time


  class ChangeRole(unittest.TestCase, DriverAndLogin):
```

But the variable "self.driver" or "driver" is not visible in second file.

P.S: 
I tried with:

```
 from SeleniumOOP.DriverAndLogin import DriverAndLogin
 import unittest
 from selenium import webdriver


class ChangeRole(unittest.TestCase, metaclass=DriverAndLogin):

    def setUp(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
         self.driver.maximize_window()

    def see_the_role(self):
         driver = self.driver
         therole = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Person_Title').text
         print(therole)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

But I get the error: "TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

Comment: "I want to create another file and class to continue first file and class" => I'm not sure to understand what you __really__ mean by this but one thing is sure: "continuing a file and class" just doesn't make sense (it's a syntactically correct sentence, but about as sensible as "I want my rhodoid to grow a tractor and squash the sea").

Comment: Also I'm not sure you really understand what inheritance is nor how to use it (and let's not talk about metaclasses).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers My first class is stopped after Login, and I want to create a class who call the first class and continue this! So, in second class (and file) I want to run first class + another code who continue the first class from where it stayed. Now you understand?

Comment: "My first class is stopped after Login" and "code who continue the first class from where it stayed" don't make sense. A class is not "stopped" and it doesn't "stay" anywhere. I understand what you want to do - first test that you can login, then test that if you're logged in you can "see the role", but this has nothing to do with a "class being stopped" or "a class continuing where the first class stayed".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't calling `ChangeRole.setUp()` before trying to access `self.driver`.

```
class ChangeRole(DriverAndLogin):
    def printDriver(self):
        print(self.driver)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ch = ChangeRole()
    ch.setUp()
    ch.printDriver()
```

This should work as intended.

If you don't want to call `setUp` before, you should consider adding it to your `__init__` function:

```
class ChangeRole(DriverAndLogin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setUp()

    def printDriver(self):
        print(self.driver)
```

This way, `setUp()` is called every time an instance of the class is created. Depending on what you want to do with the `DriverAndLogin` class, it might also be a good idea to add a call to `setUp()` to `DriverAndLogin.__init__`.

Comment: I get : "TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases TestCase, DriverAndLogin"

Comment: @ConstantinValentin This was because DriverAndLogin already inherited from unittest.TestCase, so there are problems if you inherit ChangeRole from DriverAndLogin and TestCase. I edited my answer, now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you really want to do (the real problem, not what you think is the solution) is to 1. test that you can login and 2. test that if you're logged in you can "see the role".

The solution here is not to "have a class that continue where the first has stopped" (which makes no sense at all), but to have two test methods in your `TestCase` class and factor out the login part:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
       self.driver.maximize_window()

    # this is a normal method and won't be called
    # directly by the test runner
    def login(self):
       driver = self.driver
       driver.get('https://qa.knolyx.com/')
       self.assertIn("Login to your account | Knolyx", driver.title)
       time.sleep(1)
       search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
       search_box.send_keys('username@test.com')
       password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
       password.send_keys("98765")
       button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div > div > form > div.Login_Actions > button')
       button_login.click()
       time.sleep(1)


    def test_login(self):
       self.login()
       self.assertIn("Dashboard | Knolyx", self.driver.title)


    def test_can_see_role(self):
       self.login()
       driver = self.driver
       therole = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Person_Title').text
       print(therole)
```

A TestCase can have has many tests as you want, each will be executed in isolation by the testrunner, so technically you do not need two different classes nor two different files. You can also have as many testcases as you want in a same file.

Now if you really want to split this in different testcases (and eventually in different files), define a mixin class with the common parts (here the `setUp` and `login` method and use multiple inheritance:

```
class DriverAndLoginMixin(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    # this is a normal method and won't be called
    # directly by the test runner
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://qa.knolyx.com/')
        self.assertIn("Login to your account | Knolyx", driver.title)
        time.sleep(1)
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
        search_box.send_keys('username@test.com')
        password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        password.send_keys("98765")
        button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#app > div > div > form > div.Login_Actions > button')
        button_login.click()
        time.sleep(1)



class LoginTest(DriverAndLoginMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
       self.login()
       self.assertIn("Dashboard | Knolyx", self.driver.title)


class AnotherTest(DriverAndLoginMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    def test_can_see_role(self):
       self.login()
       driver = self.driver
       therole = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Person_Title').text
       print(therole)
```